# How to close modals in project that uses NgRX to manage state

Tags: angular, ngrx

Is there any good solution when working with modals in a project where state is managed by NgRX?

The problem I have the following:

- User clicks on button to create a new item.
- Modal window opens.
- User fills out the form and clicks on Submit.
- Dispatch an action, effects fires up and creates an item by sending HTTP request.
- Now I need to close modal on success. How do I know when to close it either inside modal component or inside component that opened this modal?

One of the solutions I see right now is to return multiple actions from the effect, one that adds created item to the store, second one to close the modal. For this I should include some modal identifier in "Create" action to identify which modal to close after "Create$" effect completes, but this will make effect more complicated.

I can't believe there is no ready solution to this problem.

I use ngx-bootstrap for modals.

UPDATE:
Seems like to make this work I need to store (state + reducer + effects + actions) open/closed status for each modal available in the application. But anyway, no existing solution?

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why are those `-1`s? I'd appreciate comments on this.

Comment: Hi, 

Any solution to this problem?

Stackblitz or any link would be of great help.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution myself that works great for me, I’ll create stackblitz a bit later. In short: I create a separate effects class for each modal which will hold modal instance and handle all related effects (open, submit, submit success and failure) and open/close its modal.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use an effect to handle the whole dialog flow, from opening the dialog to saving the entity and closing the dialog afterwards.

```
@Effect()
openDialog = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(LoginActionTypes.OpenLoginDialog),
  exhaustMap(_ => {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginDialog);
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }),
  map((result: any) => {
    if (result === undefined) {
      return new CloseDialog();
    }
    return new LoginDialogSuccess(result);
  }),
);
```

See [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#2-handling-the-flow-of-a-angular-material-dialog) for more info.

Comment: `dialogRef.afterClosed` is observable that notifies when dialog finished closing. My question was how to close dialog. Submit button on the modal window will dispatch action `createItem({item: form.value})` which is async and returns nothing obviously, and actual request is made by effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject `NgbActiveModal` in the constructor of the component and call the method `close(REASON)` on it.  So in the component you do:

```
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class ResetConfirmationComponent {

    constructor(
        public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
    ) { }
}
```

And in the template for that component:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-default"
    (click)="activeModal.close('Reason for being closed ...')">
    Submit
</button>
<button type="button" 
    (click)="activeModal.dismiss('closed')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

I don't know how you could close the dialog "on success".  The `open()` method of `NgbModal` returns an Observable when `close()` was called on the `NgbActiveModal` (as opposed to calling `dismiss()` on it).  If the operation was not successful, you should dispatch a failure action, and then re-open the dialog in another effect.

You can find a complete example repository showing the use of actions and effects: https://github.com/gflohr/ngbmodal-ngrx

Additional explanations and comments: http://www.guido-flohr.net/angular-bootstrap-modals-with-ngrx/